# Is it possible to have the technician and the reference computer on the same computer; windows7 with WAIK?

Tags: windows-7, waik

Can you have both the technician and the reference computer on the same computer; windows7 with WAIK?

You take an image an put it under c:\Images for example. So you both capture from the same and put the image in the same computer?

Answer (score 0):

That is not recommended, as running sysprep on your technician computer will remove it from the domain (if you are on one), re-set your activation, remove all drivers (unless otherwise specified in the answer file), etc... If anything goes wrong, you could break the technician computer and would need to rebuild it from scratch. Also, you would be including the WAIK files in the image, adding about 1.7 GB to the size of your image.